# React JS - disable a button if the input field is empty?

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, next.js, use-state

**React Code:**

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const autoComplete = (e) => {
    setText({ value: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <form>

      <input type="text" placeholder="search here" onChange={autoComplete} />

      <button type="submit" disabled={!text}> find </button>

    </form>
  );
}
```

SandBox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-panini-slpll

---

**Problem:**

when Page Loads, the **find** button is **disabled** at first because the `input` field is empty which is good. **But**,

Now, when I start typing something. then **delete** them all with `Backspace` key. the `find` button is not disabling again.

---

**I want:**

I just want to have my `find` button disabled if the input field is `empty`

Where I'm doing wrong?

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common mistake coming from Class Components, state setter in hooks does not merge state value as in classes.

You initialized your state as a string (`useState('')`) and then assigned it as an object

```
const autoComplete = (e) => {
    setText({ value: e.target.value });
};

// State is an object { value: 'some text' }
```

Fix your set state call:

```
const autoComplete = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
};

// State is a string 'some text'
```

Then to be more verbose you want to check if the string is empty:

```
<button disabled={text === ''}>find</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
disabled={!text.value}
```

Should do the trick.
With this function

```
const autoComplete = (e) => {
  setText({ value: e.target.value });
};
```

you are writing your input in `text.value`, not in `text`.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for check text

```
<button type="submit" disabled={text==''}> find </button>
```